# Wordpress themes that are browser tested and maintained?

Tags: themes, testing, browser-compatibility

Are there any developers that offer themes that have a defined list of browsers tested, on desktop and mobile devices, that are also periodically updated to account for new browser versions?

Comment: Look for a theme coder that is following some quality control standards within their project management. Normally if things turn out wrong, they should get fixed, that includes end-user feedback and pre-release browser testing.

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm after. Are there any theme library operators that make these kinds of guarantees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, well, I've found http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress

Details on each theme include:
Compatible browsers
WordPress version
Documentation detail
Layout type
Types of source files included
Widget ready

Looks pretty good to me. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

New browser versions not only follow standards more closely but are very well coded for rendering almost anything. There are no real forward compatibility issues when it comes to styling (outside bugs).

Modern browsers can render garbage code as though it was written by Tim Berners-Lee. If a template works in IE6 and IE7 you can rest assured it will render in any versions above that since the vast majority of problems are related to Microsoft.

If you have specific needs (mobile, email, accessibility) there are various testing applications for rendering sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Am I really expecting too much from a theme developer to actually define what browsers they have tested their themes on though? While I do test a theme that I decide on, it would be great to have assurance from the developer that they have tested thoroughly as well. A recent example didn't render correctly on Firefox 3, but fine up from that. A table with ticks and crosses for which browsers were tested is a good start.